# "... is five story" VS "is a five-storied ..."

Tags: adjectives

Can we use both constructions without thinking about the difference?

> 1. This is a five-storied house.
> 2. This house is five storey.

Comment: You can also use "has".  *The house has two storeys.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can't say "This house is five story" because *story* is a countable noun; it would have to at least be "This house is five **stories**".  ([Also, *storey* and *storeys* are mainly British; in the US, we usually write *story* and *stories*.](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/storey_story.htm))

*Five-storied house* is acceptable and normal.  For example, here's a real usage of "two-storied house":

> [This two-storied house is located in an urban area...](https://books.google.com/books?id=4demO8vjCFgC&pg=PA36&dq=%22storied%20house%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju7-eD1tTTAhUW0IMKHWwiAO0Q6AEITzAI)

*Is five storeys/stories* is also acceptable and normal.  Here are some uses of that kind of phrase:

> [...the house is three storeys.](https://books.google.com/books?id=xwEplhYGPIAC&pg=PT25&dq=%22house%20is%22%20%22storeys%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn3eu01tTTAhWq1IMKHRARAx4Q6AEIRTAG#v=onepage&q=%22house%20is%22%20%22storeys%22&f=false)
>
> [If your house is two storeys or more, you will need an extension ladder.](https://books.google.com/books?id=4YheIncANBsC&pg=PA88&dq=%22house%20is%20two%20storeys%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL_7iu19TTAhVnw4MKHcsfB_0Q6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=%22house%20is%20two%20storeys%22&f=false)

However, it sounds more fluent and is more common to say the house *has* five stories or *is five stories high*.

Comment: **five-storey** would be understood as an adjective. There's no need for the plural. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20two%20storey%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: ok, I understand.